# Doraemon - Nobita's marksheet has ticks on it

Tags: doraemon

I noticed that Nobita's marksheet has all the questions ticked, yet he still gets a 0.

[image: marksheet]

Is this a cultural thing where you don't put crosses on a paper or a mistake on the part of the animators?

Comment: I had some teachers that did would grade like this. Stripe meaning wrong, blank or a curl meaning correct.